# Set Author of a saved post as its parent post author

Tags: wordpress

I try to change author of saved harmonogram item with author of parent but those to functions seems not to work - empty i think. When i set the author id with constant value everything works.

```
 $parent_post_id = wp_get_post_parent_id($post_id);

   $post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
```

Here is whole function

```
    function func_auto_update_post_author( $post_id ) { 
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

if ( "harmonogram" != $post_type ) return;

   //$parent_post_id = get_queried_object_id();
   $parent_post_id = wp_get_post_parent_id($post_id);

   $post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author',  $parent_post_id );
         $my_post = array(
            'ID'            => $post_id,
            'post_author'   => $post_author_id,  
        );

        remove_action('save_post', 'func_auto_update_post_author');
        wp_update_post($my_post);
        add_action( 'save_post', 'func_auto_update_post_author');
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'func_auto_update_post_author');
```

Comment: _"empty i think"_ - don't "think" - _verify_. Use `var_dump` to see what your variables actually contain.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code :

```
function func_auto_update_post_author( $post_id ) 
{ 
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    if ( "harmonogram" != $post_type ) return;
    $parent_post_id = wp_get_post_parent_id($post_id);
    if($parent_post_id)
    {
         $post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $parent_post_id );
         $my_post = array(
            'ID'            => $post_id,
            'post_author'   => $post_author_id
        );
        wp_update_post($my_post);
     }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'func_auto_update_post_author');
```

you can track if any error occurred during post update by putting below code in above action hook:

```
$post_id = wp_update_post( $my_post, true );                          
if (is_wp_error($post_id)) {
    $errors = $post_id->get_error_messages();
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help!